# How to Disable AOT in Xamarin IOS when deploy to iPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

My solution consists of 3 projects:

1. My backend project with assembly My_Test_App (portable)
2. My_Test_App.Android
3. My_Test_App.iOS

I develop using VS2015 and use mac to build and deploy. It works fine in iOS simulator. My iOS project do not use linker. Also i have LLVM and incremental build already unchecked.

But when i tried to debug to iPhone device, i got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not AOT the assembly/Users/myMacName/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/64/Build/My_Test_App.dll'    My_Test_App.iOS
```

My question is:

1. How do you disable the AOT in the Xamarin.iOS project? When i check the csproj file of the iOS project, it does not have  like in the droid project.
2. Is disabling the AOT the correct way to solve it?

Thank you for answering!

My build log:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: My_Test_App.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: My_Test_App.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.1.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
1>  My_Test_App.Droid -> D:\Project\2017\Xamarin Test\test-mobile\My Test App\My_Test_App.Droid\bin\Debug\My_Test_App.Droid.dll
2>  Generated session id: c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee
2>  Generated build app name: My_Test_App.iOS
2>  Connecting to Mac server MTMAC22s-Mac-mini.local...
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
2>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Numerics, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\System.Numerics.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
2>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
2>D:\Project\2017\Xamarin Test\test-mobile\My Test App\My_Test_App.iOS\Renderers\CustomLabelRenderer.cs(143,53,143,69): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
2>  My_Test_App.iOS -> D:\Project\2017\Xamarin Test\test-mobile\My Test App\My_Test_App.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\My_Test_AppiOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: myemail@mycompany.com (HDZY35YSCS)" (6E0C54049FD692EBF4A54BBD72889DC336388268)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.yourcompany.MyTestApp" (8f408fd0-90e0-4031-92e8-a6a56530778a)
2>    Bundle Id: com.yourcompany.MyTestApp
2>    App Id: F8AZP5FC9H.com.yourcompany.MyTestApp
2>  Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Net.Primitives.dll
2>  AOTID BE85C9F7-62C4-0559-D329-FA98D6ECDAF2
2>  Code: 0(0%) Info: 0(0%) Ex Info: 0(0%) Unwind Info: 0(0%) Class Info: 7(2%) PLT: 1(0%) GOT Info: 236(71%) Offsets: 86(26%) GOT: 120
2>  Compiled: 0/0 (100%), No GOT slots: 0 (100%), Direct calls: 0 (100%)
2>  Output file: '/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Net.Primitives.dll.arm64.s'.
2>  Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_Net_Primitives_info'.
2>  JIT time: 0 ms, Generation time: 0 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
2>  /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/eglib/src/ghashtable.c:549: assertion 'hash != NULL' failed
2>  Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
2>  AOTID 77D080C4-2116-2E71-9BA1-0FB994D16E87
2>  Code: 0(0%) Info: 0(0%) Ex Info: 0(0%) Unwind Info: 0(0%) Class Info: 7(2%) PLT: 1(0%) GOT Info: 236(71%) Offsets: 86(26%) GOT: 120
2>  Compiled: 0/0 (100%), No GOT slots: 0 (100%), Direct calls: 0 (100%)
2>  Output file: '/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll.arm64.s'.
2>  Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_Xml_ReaderWriter_info'.
2>  JIT time: 0 ms, Generation time: 0 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
2>  /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/eglib/src/ghashtable.c:549: assertion 'hash != NULL' failed
2>  Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/My_Test_AppiOS.exe
2>  AOTID 298562A7-A350-2A44-1D0B-2E4FC728F9D1
2>  Code: 54748(65%) Info: 456(0%) Ex Info: 19951(23%) Unwind Info: 1136(1%) Class Info: 4700(5%) PLT: 190(0%) GOT Info: 2018(2%) Offsets: 626(0%) GOT: 2872
2>  Compiled: 97/97 (100%), No GOT slots: 0 (0%), Direct calls: 15 (37%)
2>  Output file: '/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/My_Test_AppiOS.exe.arm64.s'.
2>  Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_My_Test_AppiOS_info'.
2>  JIT time: 21 ms, Generation time: 25 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
2>  AOT Compilation exited with code 139, command:
2>  MONO_PATH=/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt  --aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/My_Test_App.arm64.aotdata,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/My_Test_App.dll.arm64.s "/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/My_Test_App.dll"
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(696,3): error : Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/mtmac22/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/My_Test_App.iOS/c7eaf4168fcb1f8aaecd3a6cbb0f37ee/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/My_Test_App.dll'
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.AOTTask.Build () [0x00117] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask v) [0x00000] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
2>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEachWorker>c__AnonStorey6`2[TSource,TLocal].<>m__0 (System.Int32 i) [0x00012] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
2>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForWorker>c__AnonStorey3`1[TLocal].<>m__1 () [0x000ed] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You cannot disable AOT on iOS, your project won't work as iDevices do not allow JIT'ing
2. No unfortunately no.

We'd need a longer build log (add '-v -v -v' as 'mtouch' arguments), but it can happen because the assembly is too big. you might want to enable Linking All Assemblies in the iOS project settings.

See this for additional references: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/457/error-could-not-aot-the-assembly-servicestack-text-monotouch-dll

Comment: Hi Stephane, Thanks for answering. I have edited my post with the build output.  I check the size of the assembly in question, and the size is only 441KB. Is that size considered big?

I also have tried Linking all assemblies, but that would introduce another errors and requires me to do heavy modifications of the existing code which i sadly don't have time for it..

Comment: @prinnny this answer already contains a clear "No, impossible" message. Whether you have time or not, you cannot get Xamarin.iOS to work on iOS device without AOT. Spend time on that if you want to finish the project. It is very likely that you will have to contact Xamarin support team and share your source files with them, as there were old threads like https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36371